# jQuery select element with class added dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a button, which when clicked adds a class to a different button. I then have a selector which is set up for that button but only when the class is present. If the first button hasn't been clicked, the selector for the second should be invalid. However, even when I have clicked the first button it still is not working.

I thought `.live()` used to cover this, and later (once `live` was deprecated) `.on()` would cover this.

Anyone know what I need to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/p39gZ/1/

**jQuery**

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('#button2').addClass('active');
});

$('#button2.active').on('click', function(){
    alert("");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Add Class" />
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Button with event listener" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try this using [**.hasClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$('#button2').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        alert("active");
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p39gZ/9/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind the click event to a container element that is present when the DOM is loaded, then pass in the active class as a parameter with the .on()-method.
Example below is with a div with id of "container" wrapping both buttons.

```
 $('#container').on('click', '.active', function() {
      alert('clicked');
 });
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p39gZ/2/

Comment: Wow, I'd never seen that before, it appears to be referred to as a "delegated event" on the documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events, it's an interesting read. What you say definitely makes sense, it can't bind an event if the selector can't find anything on document load. Thanks for your solution, I prefer it over checking for a class with an `If` statement.

Comment: Oh, apologies, I should have read this more carefully. I need a container to do this? Why can it not just have a click event on the button itself? Makes the `If` statements far more appealing, less HTML markup!

Comment: @ChrisNicholson You can bind it to any existing parent element. If there is nothing else you can also use `document`.

Comment: How would I solve the instance where some other element exists with same class?: http://jsfiddle.net/p39gZ/13/

Comment: For example: `$('#container').on('click', 'input[type="button"].active', function(){`. But using the same `active` class for such different things doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Ah I see, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/p39gZ/14/. Yes I agree the use case is a bit strange but just so I understand it fully should I use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('#button2').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).attr('class') == "active")
        alert("Active Clicked");
});
```

Refer this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p39gZ/4/)