# jQuery select and deselect element with dynamically changed onclick class

Tags: jquery, html

i have 5 container with different id's. 
inside each container i have an button to select the current and connected containers.

So far the selection of the containers works as expected. 
But when i want to deselect an container ist doesn't work.

Please ignore the calculation part of the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var pricepermod = '';
var priceperemp = '';
var priceperloc = '';
var priceperusr = '';
var priceperpor = '';
var price = '';

$("#price-calculator input").change(function(){
    $(this).pricecalc();
});

$.fn.pricecalc = function(){
    var pricepermod = 10;
    var priceperemp = 1;
    var priceperloc = 10;
    var priceperusr = 10;
    var priceperpor = 1;
    // alert("funktion aufgerufen");
    var priceemp = $("#numemp").val()  * priceperemp;
    var priceloc = $("#numloc").val()  * priceperloc;
    var priceusr = $("#hruser").val()  * priceperusr;
    var pricepor = $("#empport").val() * priceperpor;
    var pricemod = $("#nummod").val()  * pricepermod;
    price = pricemod + priceemp + priceloc + priceusr + pricepor;
    $("#moncost").val(price);
}

$("#dpa.pricebox a.pricebutton").click(function() {
    alert( "DPA" );
    pricepermod = 1;
    $("#nummod").val(pricepermod);
    $("#dpa").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#dms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#mms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#tms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#bms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#mms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#dpa a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#tms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#bms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $(this).pricecalc();
    event.preventDefault();
});

$("#dpa.pricebox-selected > a.pricebutton").click(function() {
    alert( "DPA selected" );
    pricepermod = 0;
    $("#nummod").val(pricepermod);
    $("#dpa").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#dms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#mms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#tms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#bms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#mms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#dms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#dpa a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#tms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#bms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $(this).pricecalc();
    event.preventDefault();
});


$("#dms.pricebox a.pricebutton").click(function() {
    alert( "DMS" );
    pricepermod = 2;
    $("#nummod").val(pricepermod);
    $("#dpa").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#dms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#mms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#tms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#bms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#dpa a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#mms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#tms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#bms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $(this).pricecalc();
    event.preventDefault();
});
$("#dms.pricebox-selected a.pricebutton").click(function() {
    alert( "DMS selected" );
    pricepermod = 1;
    $("#nummod").val(pricepermod);
    $("#dpa").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#dms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#mms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#tms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#bms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#mms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#dpa a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#tms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#bms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $(this).pricecalc();
    event.preventDefault();
});


$("#mms.pricebox a.pricebutton").click(function() {
    alert( "MMS" );
    pricepermod = 3;
    $("#nummod").val(pricepermod);
    $("#dpa").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#dms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#mms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#tms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#bms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#dms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dpa a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#mms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#tms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#bms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $(this).pricecalc();
    event.preventDefault();
});
$("#mms.pricebox-selected a.pricebutton").click(function() {
    alert( "MMS selected" );
    pricepermod = 2;
    $("#nummod").val(pricepermod);
    $("#dpa").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#dms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#mms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#tms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#bms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#mms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dpa a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#tms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#bms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $(this).pricecalc();
    event.preventDefault();
});

$("#tms.pricebox a.pricebutton").click(function() {
    alert( "TMS" );
    pricepermod = 4;
    $("#nummod").val(pricepermod);
    $("#dpa").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#dms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#mms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#tms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#bms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#dms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dpa a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#mms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#tms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#bms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $(this).pricecalc();
    event.preventDefault();
});
$("#tms.pricebox-selected a.pricebutton").click(function() {
    alert( "TMS selected" );
    pricepermod = 3;
    $("#nummod").val(pricepermod);
    $("#dpa").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#dms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#mms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#tms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#bms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#mms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dpa a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#tms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $("#bms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $(this).pricecalc();
    event.preventDefault();
});

$("#bms.pricebox a.pricebutton").click(function() {
    alert( "BMS" );
    pricepermod = 5;
    $("#nummod").val(pricepermod);
    $("#dpa").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#dms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#mms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#tms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#bms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#dms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dpa a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#mms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#tms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#bms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $(this).pricecalc();
    event.preventDefault();
});
$("#bms.pricebox-selected a.pricebutton").click(function() {
    alert( "BMS selected" );
    pricepermod = 4;
    $("#nummod").val(pricepermod);
    $("#dpa").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#dms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#mms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#tms").removeClass("pricebox").addClass("pricebox-selected");
    $("#bms").removeClass("pricebox-selected").addClass("pricebox");
    $("#mms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#dpa a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#tms a.pricebutton").html("deselect");
    $("#bms a.pricebutton").html("select");
    $(this).pricecalc();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

```
<body>

    <div id="dpa" class="pricebox">
        <h2>DPA</h2>
        <a href="#" class="pricebutton">auswählen</a>
    </div>
    <div id="dms" class="pricebox">
        <h2>DMS</h2>
        <a href="#" class="pricebutton">auswählen</a>
    </div>
    <div id="mms" class="pricebox">
        <h2>MMS</h2>
        <a href="#" class="pricebutton">auswählen</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tms" class="pricebox">
        <h2>TMS</h2>
        <a href="#" class="pricebutton">auswählen</a>
    </div>
    <div id="bms" class="pricebox">
        <h2>BMS</h2>
        <a href="#" class="pricebutton">auswählen</a>
    </div>


    <form id="price-calculator">
        <p>Anzahl Mitarbeiter <input type="text" name="numemp" id="numemp" class="form-control" value="0"></p>
        <hr />
        <p>Anzahl Standorte <input type="text" name="numloc" id="numloc" class="form-control" value="0"></p>
        <p>Anzahl HR-Anwender <input type="text" name="hruser" id="hruser" class="form-control" value="0"></p>
        <p>Anzahl Mitarbeiterportale <input type="text" name="empport" id="empport" class="form-control" value="0"></p>
        <hr />
        <p>gewählte Module <input type="text" name="nummod" id="nummod" class="form-control" value="0" /></p>
        <p>Monatliches Nutzungsentgeld <input type="text" name="moncost" id="moncost" class="form-control" value="0" /> (&euro;/mtl.)</p>
    </form>

</body>
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mrwrm98/)

Can somebody please help me here? 
I am already trying different solutions i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056322/jquery-select-element-with-class-added-dynamically), but nothing seems to work :(

PS: sorry for the bad code. I am not an jQuery expert.

Comment: update your fiddle page link. It is not working

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle the `.pricebox-selected` css class `onClick`.
This is just an example of a very generic behavior, i think you can figure out the rest of the code by yourself.

**EDIT As a followup to your comment:**
The inner logic is up to you, i just wanted to show that it can be more generic with less code. i updated the code, i chose one of many ways to handle with dependent element, i just added them to a data-* attribute and grabbed them on the `onClick` event.
Like i said, this is one way of many.

```js
$(document).on('click','.pricebox a',function(e){
  var $currentBox = $(this).parent('.pricebox');
  var dependencies = $currentBox.attr('data-dependencies') || [];
  var selectedClass = 'pricebox-selected';
  
  // remove all
  $('.pricebox').removeClass(selectedClass);
  
  // set current
  $currentBox.addClass(selectedClass);
  
  // set dependencies
  $(dependencies.toString()).addClass(selectedClass);
  console.clear();
  console.log(dependencies.toString());
  console.log($currentBox.attr('id'));
});
```

```css
.pricebox 
 {
  width:100px;
  min-height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
 }
 .pricebox-selected 
 {
  width:100px;
  min-height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background-color:#4169E1;
 }
  
 a.pricebutton 
 {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px 10px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:10px auto 0 auto;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:1px solid #666;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dpa" data-dependencies="" class="pricebox">
  <h2>DPA</h2>
  <a href="#" class="pricebutton">select</a>
 </div>
 <div id="dms" data-dependencies="#dpa" class="pricebox">
  <h2>DMS</h2>
  <a href="#" class="pricebutton">select</a>
 </div>
 <div id="mms" class="pricebox">
  <h2>MMS</h2>
  <a href="#" class="pricebutton">select</a>
 </div>
 <div id="tms" data-dependencies="#dpa,#dms,#mms" class="pricebox">
  <h2>TMS</h2>
  <a href="#" class="pricebutton">select</a>
 </div>
 <div id="bms" data-dependencies="#dpa,#dms,#mms,#tms" class="pricebox">
  <h2>BMS</h2>
  <a href="#" class="pricebutton">select</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I've added the alert just to demonstrate that you can grab relevant data as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that does not work with the dependencies I have in this case.
The dependencies of the containers are as follows: 

If DPA is selected nothing else must be selected. 
If DMS is selected, DPA must also be automatically selected. 
If MMS is selected, DPA, DMS must also be automatically selected. 
If TMS is selected, DPA, DMS, MMS must also be automatically selected. 
If BMS is selected, DPA, DMS, MMS, TMS must also be automatically selected.

Comment: This is great and a completely different approach. Looks much easier and cleaner.  
But unfortunately I do not know how I can integrate 2 of my previous functions into it. 
 
In each box is a button with class .pricebutton with the value "select". If the box is selected, the value of the button must also change to deselect. 
In addition, I must count how many boxes were selected and pass the value into a variable "pricepermod". 
Can I somehow integrate this into the function?

Comment: of course you can, if you want to count selected elements just mark them with a `class` (i showed you how to do it) and grab them with jQuery selector, if you need a toggle behavior you can either use a logic like `$(this).hasClass('selected')`  or even take a different approach and use `checkbox` and just check if the relevant elements are checked. you got a lot of options but i can't write the code for you, i was just trying to answer your question and provide you with a start point :)